# Minimizar arquivo CSS com o Grunt

Tags: javascript

Galera gostaria de saber como faço para criar meu css em uma linha só com o grunt, segue meu código abaixo

```js
// Copy source assets to _gh_pages
    copy: {
      assets: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= site.assets %>/public',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '<%= site.dest %>/public/'
          },
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= site.assets %>/root',
            src: ['*'],
            dest: '<%= site.dest %>/',
            rename: function (dest, src) {
            dest = dest + src.replace(/^_/, '');
            return dest;
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Para minificar arquivos `CSS`, um pacote amplamente usado é o `grunt-contrib-cssmin`. Você pode instalar através do comando `npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin --save-dev`.

Depois de instalado, você precisa carregar o pacote no Gruntfile:

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');`

Uma tarefa simples para executar o que você precisa (neste caso, inclusive, combinando dois arquivos para somente uma saída CSS):

```
cssmin: {
  target: {
    files: {
      'output.css': ['foo.css', 'bar.css']
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Você está no caminho certo!

Neste seu código a única coisa que você está fazendo é copiar seus arquivos de uma pasta para outra. Agora falta "minificar", que é um processo que você irá realizar nesses arquivos que você copiou. Para tal, você precisa do `uglify`.

Separei uma lista de tutoriais que vão te ajudar bastante em entender como criar seus scripts Grunt:

- [Automatizando Tarefas com Grunt](https://zenorocha.com/automatizando-tarefas-js-com-grunt)
- [Automação de build com GruntJS](http://blog.caelum.com.br/automacao-de-build-de-front-end-com-grunt-js/)
- [GruntJS: por onde começar?](http://www.voltsdigital.com.br/labs/gruntjs-por-onde-comecar/)
- [Grunt: você deveria estar usando](http://tableless.com.br/grunt-voce-deveria-estar-usando/)

Boa leitura!